# The minimum value of the sum $O_1O_2+…+O_{n-1}O_n$

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, 3d

A cube  C of side $n > 2, n ∈ N,$ is divided in $n^3$ cubes of side 1, with disjoint interiors two by two.

We say that two of the cubes of side 1 are Olympic, if any plane parallel to any of the faces of cube C intersects at most one of the interiors of these cubes. We choose the cubes $C_1, C_2,…, C_n$  olympics two by two,and denote with $O_1,…, O_n$ their centers. Determine the minimum value of the sum $O_1O_2+…+O_{n-1}O_n$ and establish which are the configurations formed by n cubes of side 1 for which this minimum is reached.

I think the minimum is $(n-1)\sqrt 3$ but I don’t know to prove.

Comment: Most of the solution is just unpacking the notation.  Have you investigated what "Olympic" means on an intuitive level?  (For your benefit, you may want to align $xyz$-axes so that the $xy$, $xz$ and $yz$ coordinate planes are parallel to the sides of the cube)

Comment: @ale forget about cubes. Try to solve the question for $n^2$ unit squares (replace planes with lines). Can you get $(n-1)\sqrt2$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think that The right configuration it's on The diagonal of cube. But how to prove that it is the minimum value?

Comment: To show it's the minimum value, just focus on a single term.  Can you see why $O_1O_2 \geq \sqrt{3}$? If it's hard to see that directly, keep in mind the alignment I mentioned in my first comment.  Can you see why the distance between the $x$ coordinates of $O_1$ and $O_2$ is $\geq 1$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring unfortunately no. I didn't use The System axis until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my hint in the comments, let's solve this problem of $n \times n$ unit squares.

We replace planes by lines. In an $n \times n$ grid, if any line parallel to the gridlines does not intersect the interior of more than one square, all squares must belong on different rows and columns. (This is equivalent to placing $n$ mutually non-attacking rooks on an $n \times n$ chessboard.)

Now, we show $O_iO_{i+1} \ge \sqrt 2$. 
By Pythagoras, $O_{i}O_{i+1} = \sqrt{d_c^2 + d_r^2}$, where $d_c$ is the difference in there column numbers, and $d_r$ is the difference in their row numbers. By the hypothesis, $d_c,d_r \ge 1$. So,
$$O_{i}O_{i+1} \ge \sqrt{1^2+1^2} = \sqrt 2$$

---

Analogously, in the 3D version, show that $O_{i}O_{i+1} \ge \sqrt 3$, by noting that
$$O_{i}O_{i+1} = \sqrt{d_x^2+d_y^2+d_z^2}$$
where $d_x$ is the difference in their $x$ co-ordinates, etc.

Since you already have a construction for the equality case, the claim is proven.